# vim-go: permission denied installing 'gopls'

Tags: linux, go, vim, gopath, vim-go

I'm trying to setup the vim-go in a work environment but I don't have permission to install the gopls using:

```
GoInstallBinaris
```

or

```
go get golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest
```

I'm getting this: /path/go/bin/gopls: permission denied

Is there a way to fix this issue setting up secondary GOPATH just for VIM?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to change GOPATH, set it to a new value and make sure to update PATH.

Comment: Probably what you are looking for https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/issues/2166